# Python regular expressions: Better way to handle non-matches?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, coding-style

When I deal with regular expressions, my code is littered with conditionals so as to not create exceptions when a pattern is not found:

```py
m = some_compiled_pattern.match(s)
if m:
    x = m.groups()
    do_something_with(x)
m = some_other_compiled_pattern.search(s):
if m:
    y = m.groupdict()
else:
    y = {}
do_something_else_with(y)
```

Isn't there a better (less verbose) way to handle such exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this class useful to reduce most of those if-no-match handling to a one line.

```py
class Returns:
    """
    Makes an object that pretends to have all possible methods, 
    but returns the same value (default None) no matter what this method, 
    or its arguments, is.
    """

    def __init__(self, return_val=None):
        self.return_val = return_val

        def the_only_method_there_is(*args, **kwargs):
            return return_val

        self.the_only_method_there_is = MethodType(the_only_method_there_is, self)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if not item.startswith('_') and item not in {'return_val', 'the_only_method_there_id'}:
            return self.the_only_method_there_is
        else:
            return getattr(self, item)
```

Example use:

```py
    >>> import re
    >>> p = re.compile(r'(\d+)\W+(\w+)')
    >>>
    >>> # when all goes well...
    >>> m = p.search('The number 42 is mentioned often')
    >>> num, next_word = m.groups()
    >>> num, next_word
    ('42', 'is')
    >>>
    >>> # when the pattern is not found...
    >>> m = p.search('No number here')
    >>> assert m is None  # m is None so...
    >>> num, next_word = m.groups()  # ... this is going to choke
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      ...
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
    >>>
    >>> # Returns to the rescue
    >>> num, next_word = (p.search('No number here') or Returns((None, 'default_word'))).groups()
    >>> assert num is None
    >>> next_word
    'default_word'
```

EDIT: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/thorwhalen/6c913e9be35873cea6efaf6b962fde07) for a longer discussion (and alternate but similar solution) of this problem.